# Display branch name in $PS1 on ksh88

Tags: shell, git, ksh, aix, prompt

I want to display my current git branch in the prompt in ksh88.

I'm working on a legacy project, when the backend run on IBM's AIX, with a mandatory ksh88 shell. I can switch to say, bash, for some operations, but I'm compelled to use ksh88 for most of the daily work. (we are working on changing the shell but it's a very long shot, nigh impossible)

So I'm using this (simplified) kind of variation. all of them work (they display the current branch), but none are dynamic: If I switch branch, they still display the same branch.

```
export GIT_BRANCH=$(git branch 2>/dev/null | grep '^*' | colrm 1 2)
export PS1="\$GIT_BRANCH - $ "
```

as well as

```
get_git_branch(){
    print -- git branch 2>/dev/null | grep '^*' | colrm 1 2
}
export PS1="$(get_git_branch) - $"
```

In both cases, to update it, I need to reload my .profile (running `. ~/.profile`), but that's not practical.

When I'm adding the $PWD (in my full version of the `export PS1`), it does change when I'm changing the current directory

I've read here ([How to set the command(s) that get run before every single prompt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49925/how-to-set-the-commands-that-get-run-before-every-single-prompt)) that there could be some tricks to expand some expressions, but only numerical ones.

I've seen this (my biggest hope at the moment)  [Solaris KSH setting up PS1 with dynamic line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/308921/solaris-ksh-setting-up-ps1-with-dynamic-line) but didn't quite understood how to apply it to my problem.

Is there any other tricks I could use ?

Comment: Those "tricks" work with all expressions, not only numeric ones. You're focussing on what's following the $ and not looking at what's around the whole expression.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas true! I guess I got confused after spending 2 hours on ksh88 topics and Oracle's documentation ! I edited my question.

Comment: @user1686, could you be more specific ? I retried to implement the trick of using an array, but I can't make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

Took some puzzel work.

a) use ksh93

b) these aliases give an idea of how to reset (if you want) to not have any branch info in your prompt.

- I added the following to .profile

```
ENV=~/.kshrc
export ENV
```

- I decided (see above) to keep my aliases in .kshrc. The key lines are:

```
# alias to reset PS1
alias psr="PS1=$LOGNAME@`hostname`:'\[\${PWD##*/}\]'"
# alias to set PS1 to dynamically check for git branch active, or not
alias psgit="PS1=${LOGNAME}@$(hostname -s)'\[\${PWD##*/}\]{\$(git branch 2>/dev/null| grep \"^*\" | colrm 1 2)}'"
```

*I borrowed from your question!*

My default shell is regular ksh(88). Login and switch to the prettier shell looks like this:

```
aixtools@x064:[aixtools]aixpb
aixtools@x064:[Playbook]psgit
aixtools@x064[Playbook]{$(git branch 2>/dev/null| grep ^* | colrm 1 2)}export PS1
aixtools@x064[Playbook]{$(git branch 2>/dev/null| grep ^* | colrm 1 2)}ksh93
aixtools@x064[Playbook]{master}
aixtools@x064[Playbook]{master}git checkout aixpb_main00
Updating files: 100% (44/44), done.
Switched to branch 'aixpb_main00'
Your branch is up to date with 'aixtools/aixpb_main00'.
aixtools@x064[Playbook]{aixpb_main00}cd
aixtools@x064[aixtools]{}
```

There is a typo (missing ':') - but that you can fix, as a lot of PS1 is very personal.

Hope this helps!